# Error while instantiating a chaincode on hyperledger fabric using Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain, instantiation

[error: [client-utils.js]: sendPeersProposal - Promise is rejected: Error: error starting container: error starting container: API error (404): network **example** not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jobMb.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the environment variable **CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE: "example"**  from yaml file. Now again up the blockchain network and Instantiate the chaincode you will be able to instantiate the chaincode.

This environment cause problem when you are spawning the **hyperledger fabric** on **kubernetes**. This will not cause any error when you spawning the blockchain network on docker.